# MySQL JOIN ARRAY

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to JOIN some tables then resulting as an array.

Table "fruits" are the primary table.

"fruit_id" field at table "ordered" is taken from table "fruits" id.

Table: fruits

```
------------------------------------------------------+
id          fruits          date_created
------------------------------------------------------+
1           Apple           2016-03-31 14:29:29
2           Blueberry       2016-03-30 14:22:54
3           Coconut         2016-03-30 14:19:12
------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table: ordered

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
id          fruit_id            package_id      price_with_ship         price_without_ship
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1           3                   10              150                     0   
2           3                   11              0                       110
3           2                   10              0                       87
4           2                   11              0                       95
5           2                   12              100                     0
6           1                   12              75                      0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here are the result I suggest.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Apple
            [date_created] => 2016-03-31 14:29:29
            [package_id] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 10
                                        [1] => 11
                                    )
            [price_with_ship] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 150
                                        [1] => 0
                                    )
            [price_with_ship] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 0
                                        [1] => 110
                                    )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Blueberry
            [date_created] => 2016-03-30 14:22:54
            [package_id] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 10
                                        [1] => 11
                                        [2] => 12
                                    )
            [price_with_ship] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 0
                                        [1] => 0
                                        [2] => 100
                                    )
            [price_with_ship] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 87
                                        [1] => 95
                                        [2] => 0
                                    )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Coconut
            [date_created] => 2016-03-30 14:19:12
            [package_id] => 12
            [price_with_ship] => 75
            [price_with_ship] => 0
        )
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: what output you required.

Comment: Please clarify your question. 

Are you expecting the output to be a list of fruits along with the order details for each fruit?

Comment: @Stuart yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

you can join as per below-

```
select f.*, o.* 
from fruit as f
join order as o on o.fruit_id=f.id
where f.id=1;
```

Comment: thank you. these make depends the table "ordered" rows, and not depends of "fruits" table.

Comment: Not getting what you want to say...this was just an example of join...further if you share your requirement/ouput then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 queries

1. get `id, name, date_created`:

   `Select o.id, f.name, f.date_created
    From ordered o left join fruits f ON o.fruit_id = f.id`
2. for each record select details:

   `Select package_id, price_with_ship, price_without_ship From ordered Where id = ? -- replace with id from the loop`